# REACT: Add multiple entry points in config-overrides.js file for multiple html files

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, antd

I am new to React CRA (it is rewired as per doc in ant-design description for project setup) and facing issues in adding multiple entry points in webpack-config file.

I have 2 html files in public folder, index.html & stack.html.

```
-public
  -index.html   //runs on localhost:3000
  -stack.html   // runs on localhost:3000/stack.html
-src
  -index.tsx
  -stack.tsx
-config-overrides.ts
```

Default html index.html and index.tsx is used to boot and load react components.

I created stack.html file and accordingly i have created stack.tsx file as entry point to boot and load react components. I am unable to wire things up.
What configuration should be made to wire this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do this, but you will need to eject from CRA. After that:

1. Add entry to the other html file in `paths.js`.
2. Update `entry` inside `webpack.config.js` and add the second html file entry (to be similar to the original `entry`).
3. Change the output file name inside `webpack.config.js`. Change `static/j/bundle.js` to `static/js/[name].bundle.js`.
4. Upadte webpack plugins to generate second file with injected JS scripts (also inside `webpack.config.js`).
5. Update the `ManifestPlugin` configuration to include the new entry point (also inside `webpack.config.js`).

Finally, there are two different steps for development and production.

1. For DEV, rewrite paths using the following in `webpackDevServer.config.js` (if you want to redirect all `/admin` to `admin.html` file):

```
verbose: true, 
rewrites: [
  { from: /^/admin/, to: '/admin.html' },
],
```

2. For Production, this step is different for each provider. For Heroku, it is very easy, just create a `static.json` file with the following content:

```json
{
  "root": "build/",
  "routes": {
    "/admin**": "admin.html",
    "/**": "index.html"
  }
}
```

For full details and file diffs, see [this post](https://sapandiwakar.in/multiple-html-pages-with-create-react-app-app/).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there are no good ways of doing this. 
One way is to just use react-scripts and build multiple apps by copying and replacing index.html and index.js for each build. Something like
https://gist.github.com/jkarttunen/741fd48eb441137404a168883238ddc1

Also for CRA v3, there is an open PR for fixing this: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8249